# Statement about entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions, meromorphic-functions

[image]In Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis, there is the following statement: if two entire functions, say $f_1 $,$f_2$, vanish at all $z=a_n $ and nowhere else, then $\frac {f_1}{f_2} $ has removable singularities at all the points $a_n $. Suppose $f_1$ has a simple zero in $a_1 $ and $f_2$ has a zero of order $2$ in $a_1$; then $a_1$ would be a pole for $\frac {f_1}{f_2} $. Where is the absurd in this supposition? Thanks for any clarify

Comment: I forgot to say that $\{a_n \}$ is a sequence of complex numbers with $|a_n|\to\infty $ as $n\to \infty $

Comment: You are saying that $\frac {f_1} {f_2}$ has a removable singularity as well as  a pole $a_1$. That is not possible.

Comment: In the book, a zero with multiplicity $n$ is considered $n$ times in the sequence $\{a_n\}$. In this passage it is this assumed that the two functions have the same zeros with the same multiplicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement in your book is false. Your arguments are correct.

An example: let $f_1(z)= \sin z$ and $f_2(z)= \sin^2 z.$ Then $\frac{f_1}{f_2}(z)= \frac{1}{ \sin z}.$

Each zero of $ \sin$ is a simple pole of  $\frac{f_1}{f_2}.$

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if I missed something,  I posted also the page of the book (the sentence is in the paragraph starting with "To begin with the proof").